# I can't figure out why I'm reading wrong input in reading array elements in codechef problem for reverse array problem

Tags: c#

I'm getting different user input instead of getting real inputs given by user in codechef

User Input:

```
4

1 2 3 4
```

Expected Output:
4 3 2 1

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        
        

    int N = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        

    int[] arr = new int[N];
        

    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
               arr[i] =  Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());
            }
        
            for(int j=N-1;j>=0;j--){
                Console.Write(arr[j]);
                Console.Write(" ");
        }
    }
}
```

Output I got:
32 50 32 49

Comment: are you perhaps reading the spaces as numbers too?

Comment: Hi lucibrot i did try reading it as number instead of converting but then also i got the same output and it didnt read the inputs properly

Comment: I think I was not clear enough what I mean (or maybe I'm the one who is confused, but) when you do the `Console.Read()` you are getting the first number. Next time you do it, you get the space character. Wouldn't you want to skip that one, instead of saving it?

Comment: Yes exactly that's my problem, i dont know how to read inputs without whitespaces but should not use ReadLine()

Comment: Is it a requirement to not use ReadLine()?

Comment: It seems to me like the output you are getting is in fact the character codes of the numbers. E.g. the character code of `'1'` is 49.

Comment: Hi lucidbot even with excluding whitespaces I'm getting same output and yes i'm getting character code instead of real value

Comment: 32 is 0x20 which is the Space key.

Comment: The `Console.Read` method returns an integer representing the code point of the character entered.  So, if you type `" "`, you will get a `0x20` (or 32 decimal).  If you type a `"1"`, you will get `0x31` (or 49 decimal) and so on.  If you cast the `int` you get to a `char` and then call `char.ToString();` you will get a string containing the entered character as a string (if you want it as a char, just do the cast)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you said you want to do it without `ReadLine`, let's work with your current code. There are two issues at hand.

- You should skip the spaces
- You get the character codes instead of the values

To skip the spaces, you can simply read them and do nothing with the read character. I implemented this below in a way that assumes after every number (one digit long) there will be a single space to ignore. But you could also do that in a less hacky way by checking what the read character actually is before you discard it.

To get the character code into the value, I first perform a conversion into a `char` by casting it. Then I get the numeric value, which might be a `double`. But because you *know* that your numbers are integers, we can cast that to `int`.

```cs
using System;
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        int N = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] arr = new int[N];
        
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
            arr[i] = (int)Char.GetNumericValue((char)Console.Read());
            Console.Read();
        }
        
        for(int j=N-1;j>=0;j--){
                Console.Write(arr[j]);
                Console.Write(" ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this is maybe not the best way to do this. It's just the first way I found. I haven't touched c# in a while